# Access Java public statics from XSL

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I know it's possible to call to Java methods by adding namespaces in XSL. Is it possible to access statics without using a getter like we can in Java?

java:

```
package com.package;

public class MyClass {

    public static final int myIntThatIUseLotsOfPlacesInJavaAndXSL = 123;

    //other methods, etc
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:myclass="com.package.MyClass" exclude-result-prefixes="myclass">

...

<xsl:value-of select="myclass:myIntThatIUseLotsOfPlacesInJavaAndXSL"/>

...
```

edit: I should've mentioned I'm using Xalan, but answers for other processors would be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: You need to say which XSLT processor you are asking about. Conventions for interoperating between XSLT and Java vary from one processor to another. It certainly won't be possible using your suggested syntax, because your select expression is referring to a name that will be treated as an element name.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the XSLT processor, for instance Saxon 9 and 10 in the commercial editions supports

```
<xsl:value-of select="myclass:myIntThatIUseLotsOfPlacesInJavaAndXSL()" xmlns:myclass="java:com.package.MyClass"/>
```

According to the book http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html it is not possible to "access fields in a class" from Xalan directly, the recommendation there is to set up a method to return the field's value.